# Binding variable in ForEach not update

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to change the rating star's images when another Movie card is clicked. Other text information changes but not rating stars. I am using `RatingView` which creates rating stars stack. I am first showing not rated ones then rated stars. But when I change Movie card the star's color does not change

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct RatingView: View {
    
    @Binding var movie : Movie
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ForEach(0 ..< Int(movie.getLikers())) { item in
            
                Image("star")
                    .scaleEffect(1.5)
                    .padding(10)

            }
            ForEach(0 ..< Int(movie.getDislikers())) { item in

                Image("star.fill")
                    .scaleEffect(1.5)
                    .padding(10)

            }
            Text(movie.imageName)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Move` struct/class, this will help us investigate this further.

Comment: Don't use functions, like `getLikers()` - use properties.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Could you also add a code of the place where the `RatingView` is used? I suspect the issue could be hidden there.

Answer (score 0):

change your `ForEach` constructor to use `ForEach([Hashable])`

if `movie.getDislikers()` returns `[Hashable]` and `Movie` is some sort of observed object, it will update. Here is my solution in a sample app.

```swift
struct SomeStruct: Hashable {
}



struct Sample: View {
@Binding var store: [SomeStruct]
var body: some View {
List {
   Section {
      ForEach(store, id: \.self) { (foo: SomeStruct) in
        HStack {
             Text(foo)
        }
}
}
}
```